# Windows Server log history

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have established that someone has logged into my desktop while I was on vacation, I believe it was done through our server from our administrator but I am not sure how. I am not IT friendly but I have Admin privileges on my server, so i figured before I blame the IT for accessing my Desktop i would see if he was logged on the server during the same time as it was during non working hours. Can someone provide me a step by step process on how to view previous log-ins on Server 2008

Comment: *"blame the IT for accessing my Desktop"* - You do realise that (unless you have very specific exemptions) that doing that is simply their job?

Answer (score 12):

Open the Event Viewer – press the Windows key, type Event Viewer, and press Enter to open it.

Navigate to the Windows Logs –> Security category in the event viewer.

Look for events with event ID 4624 – these represent successful login events.

Scroll down in the logs to the time you believe he logged in and have a look.

You can double click on any log to open them, usually you will see the first line:

"An account was successfully logged on."

Then several more lines down

"New Logon:

Security ID:        domain\user

Account Name:       user"

Comment: Please note the OP is stuck if auditting was not set prior to the incident. *By default, this value is set to No auditing in the Default Domain Controller Group Policy object (GPO) and in the local policies of workstations and servers. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976395.aspx)*